# Remote Desktop Connection (Mac) does not share drive/folder to the Vista target

Tags: macos, windows-vista, remote-desktop

I have a Mac OS X 10.5/Intel system, runnging RDC 2.0.1 (latest as far as I know).

When I connect to the remote Windows Vista system, I can control the remote desktop, and everything behaves as expected.

However, when I follow the instructions for "[Copy files between computers](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/help.mspx?target=31ad1a4c-0149-42db-8ce1-5f4277f47d841033&clr=99-6-0&ep=10&CTT=Category&MODE=pv&locale=en-US&usid=f66e6c61-bba9-438a-954f-41942b22f735)" or "[I can't access my Mac hard disks](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/help.mspx?clr=99-6-0&srcid=31ad1a4c-0149-42db-8ce1-5f4277f47d841033&ep=9&target=7c64a97b-fd96-4c9f-abe2-f9367733ee351033&CTT=RelatedLink)", I do not see the mount point on my Mac appear in the Windows system.

The very-nice looking site is really short on detail: like picture or screen snapshot? Both articles are pretty vague...

> The Mac disk or folder that you have
>   made available is listed with all
>   other disks and folders on your
>   Windows-based computer.

Any ideas on how to make this work? (Maybe I am looking in the wrong place, maybe this doesn't work in Vista, maybe I did something wrong?)

TIA, BenC

Comment: This would be better asked on SuperUser.com

Comment: And while I'm on this topic, why is RDC Mac in superuser? Super Users with a Mac run Windows on a local VM. Only admin get stuck with trying to control a Windows system in a data center from their Mac desktop.

Answer (score 2):

This is a super old question, but I noticed that Remote Desktop Silently ignores sharing for Home folders. It works for all directories expect for the Mac user Host folder /User/. The client does not show any errors while configuring it either.

Comment: I am unable to use the beta client, but I cannot share /Users/{name}/Downloads using the old deprecated client. Sharing another folder outside of /Users/ works with the deprecated client. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When a drive is mapped it appears on the remote machine as `\\tsclient\X` where `X` is the drive letter.

I'm not sure exactly what letter or name would be allocated to the drive on your Mac, but you should be able to navigate to `\\tsclient` and view the available mappings.

Keep in mind that regardless of how "correct" your client configuration is, the remote computer can still refuse to redirect drives. There's a group policy setting called *Do not allow drive redirection* that, when enabled, does not allow drive redirection.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd indeed. My drives are properly mapped on the target computer. I'm using RDC 2.0.0 on OS X 10.6.4, and have connected to Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008. I don't have Vista available to test with.

Comment: So it appears as a mounted-drive letter? Or a shared drive (like VirtualBox?)